# Voice recording using Alarm Manager (android)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to record voice automatically at a predefined time. The time duration of the recording can be defined as well.

I used AlarmManager and  BroadcastReceiver to trigger time based event. However, I am not sure how to create a MediaRecorder and then start and stop recording without human intervention.

Is this doable in android and what is the best way to do this?

Comment: There are lot of examples of media recorder out there why don't you try them first? Instead asking for direct answer just experiment with available answers.

Comment: MediaRecorder using the UI can be started and stoped by the user. My question was how to automate this process using a AlarmManage or BroadcastReceiver ,